# JQuery add variable to selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to add a variable to the jquery selector to add a css class in leaflet.

```
var abc = $(TEST._icon);
abc.addClass('pulse');
```

or

```
$(TEST._icon).addClass('pulse');
```

works good. now i want a variable for TEST - so i try following without success:

```
var abc = "TEST";
$(abc + "._icon").addClass('pulse');
```

can anybody help?

thank you!

Comment: If `TEST` is a global variable, `$(window[abc] + "._icon")`. If it's a local variable, you can't access it dynamically.

Comment: thank you - i have try it out. dont work... the error message is: Internal error. Error Message: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]._icon,

Comment: Sorry, I got confused about what you're doing. It should be `$(window[abc]._icon)`. You don't need concatenation.